# Setting dropdown value attributes with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0

I have used an example from the knockout tutorial stripped down to the essentials to reproduce my problem. What I cannot figure out is how to set the value attribute of the  tags in the  items. I added a value to each entry of self.availableMeals but however I try to add it to the  it just fails to populate the dropdowns at all. When I try to add optionsValue to the binding it populates the dropdowns but doesn't select the appropriate value.
Please help!

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
    </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>


// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[1])
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Comment: Can you please extend your sample code with your own code what you have tried and not working? Based on your description it is hard to follow what is working and not working... You may also create a jsfiddle as well, you can start from this one: http://jsfiddle.net/mq4ZH/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is a working jsfiddle with breaking changes commented out http://jsfiddle.net/bwbF3/

Comment: In your example, you have a surcharge dropdown, but it's not clear where the surcharge value should come from.
If I uncomment your changes, the dropdown binds as specified - it's just binding to availableMeals and displays mealName as the text for each item.  Can  you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?  Normally you wouldn't bind two dropdowns to the same array in order to show different fields.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I've stripped out the surcharge as that isn't relevant. What I'm trying to have rendered in the HTML is:

<option value="1">Standard (sandwich)</option>
<option value="2">Premium (lobster)</option>
<option value="3">Ultimate (whole zebra)</option>

instead of

<option value="">Standard (sandwich)</option>
<option value="">Premium (lobster)</option>
<option value="">Ultimate (whole zebra)</option>

New jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwbF3/1/

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I don't know why I couldn't add a value attribute to the rendered HTML but I didn't need to. All I need to do is retrieve the selected item from the model then examine that.

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <!-- this line works but doesn't try to populate value attribute OF <OPTION> -->
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
        <!-- this line tries to populate value attribute with those commented out in the javascript but doesn't work -->
        <!--<td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName', optionsValue: 'val'"></select></td>-->
    </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: showVal">Show Value</button>

// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { val: 0, mealName: "Standard (sandwich)" },
        { val: 1, mealName: "Premium (lobster)" },
        { val: 2, mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)" }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[1])
    ]);

    self.showVal = function() {
        alert(self.seats()[1].meal().val);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

so I can get (for example) one of the val values with `self.seats()[1].meal().val`

I hope this helps someone else with the same misunderstanding.

http://jsfiddle.net/bwbF3/5/

Comment: 'Keep it simple' principal. The model value will bind to set the values and you go to the model to get the values.  But you could also always set an id attribute in the data-bind:  `data-bind="attr: {id: 'myID_'+Id}"` if you had a `self.Id` in your viewmodel that represented each reservation, then just use jQuery to get the value, too.